# How to design a large view in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, autolayout

This question might be a little bit broad and not so specific but I haven't found information about it on the internet.

So basically, I'm designing a View in Xcode which contains a stack of different containers. Reviews, About Me, Calendar and Services.

So indeed, I have 4 different containers which will be displayed one after the other.

[image: Design on XCode]

The question is, how should I design this? eventually the fourth container is completely out of the "designable" view we have in xcode. Should this be done programatically instead of visually? What about constraints for autolayout, and so on.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can design large view in Xcode by using below step**

1) select view controller in storyboard
2) go to size inspector
3) simulated size change fixed to freeform
4) then set height of your view controller

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I'll just add the UIScrollView said by @bhanu.

Answer (score 1):

use `UIScrollView` and insert other views to it.

You can enlarge you view size from `size inspector` by selecting your view in `xib` and can design easily.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do it is to make 4 nibs (separated view layouts) and load each nib in your container view. You will end with 5 classes, one for each container and the last one will be the controller of the four containers. That gives you the ability to easily move in the future one of this containers to a separated view, and keeps your code organised. Regarding `Autolayout`, you can use the nibs to add constraints as you would do to your existing `Storyboard`.

Here is an example of code to load a nib to the container view:

```
UIView *calendarView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Calendar" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
[self.calendarContainerView addSubview:calendarView];
```

Comment: Thats basically what I have right now, right? I have 4 containers, each has a ViewController (UI + Code) so i can easily move the container from one side to another if needed.

Comment: If you use Nibs to create your container views, and then load it to each container in your "main" view, yes it is. But you did not say anything about nibs in the question hehe.

Comment: mmm well, when I create the container into the View Controller.. It automatically creates a ViewController (and aside I've created the specific class which extends from UIViewController, so i can handle data).

But nothing else has been created.